# Range wildcard pattern matching behaviour with case-sensitive collations

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard, collation

Using PATINDEX and a case-sensitive collation to search for upper-case letters in a string I noticed this was not yielding the desired result:

```
-- returns 1
SELECT PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%'
                    , 'abCde' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS);
```

however, specifying every letter, A-Z, does:

```
-- returns 3
SELECT PATINDEX('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%'
                    , 'abCde' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS);
```

Is my understanding of using a range in the first case incorrect? Why is the behaviour like this?

Comment: Thanks for this, I needed to extract rows starting with upper case letters only: PATINDEX('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%', [NAME] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS) = 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the range operators are a bit funny. The range of letters from A-Z is:

```
AbBcCdDeE...yYzZ
```

That is, lower case characters immediately precede their upper case counterpart. This is also fun because if you want to deal with both upper and lower case characters, in a case sensitive collation, the range A-Z excludes lower case a.

---

I should say the above, regarding how the range expands out, is based on the collations I generally work with. How the range actually expands is [collation dependent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). *If* you can find a collation where, for instance, all upper case characters occur before all lower case characters, then the range would work as you expect. (Possibly one of the binary collations?)

Comment: Spot on @Damien_The_Believer! Switching to Latin1_General_100_BIN2 yields the same result, 3, for both of the snippets in my question above.. thanks for the clarification

Comment: This article may also be helpful: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15307.patindex-case-sensitive-search.aspx