# Transact-SQL collate doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collate, patindex

I'm trying to use [PATINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms188395.aspx) function like this:

```
select PATINDEX('%[A-Z].%', 'he.llo MA. asd ' collate Cyrillic_General_CS_AS)
```

I expect it returns 9 but it returns 2.
Can someone enlight me what's wrong? I also tried to supply collate in first parameter and use Latin1_General_CS_AS instead of Cyrrilic - the same result.

Comment: A duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212110/range-wildcard-pattern-matching-behaviour-with-case-sensitive-collations

Comment: Not a duplicate but definitely the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing a BINARY comparison so it goes bit by bit.

This guys link was helpful in solving your problem.  [LINK](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15307.patindex-case-sensitive-search.aspx)

I duplicated the 2 you were getting and with the COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN it returned the expected 9.

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[A-Z].%', 'he.llo MA. asd ' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN )
```

Comment: brilliant, it works, thanks! I'll also leave my workaround I found out based on reference to possible duplicate given in comments to my question

Comment: Glad it helped.  Obviously change to any specific COLLATION you need just adding the BIN bit at the end if the Cryillic was what you were after.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my freaky workaround based on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212110/range-wildcard-pattern-matching-behaviour-with-case-sensitive-collations) (in case Matt Akers answer didn't help you):

```
select PATINDEX('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ].%', 'he.llo MA. asd ' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS)
```