# SQL:How can I make the function that change all the uppercase to lowercase and lowercase to uppercase in a string

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2016

How can I make the function that change all the uppercase to lowercase and lowercase to uppercase in a string
e.g. "HelloW world" to "hELLOw WORLD"

Comment: Looks like homework to me. What have you tried so far? Post your code.

Comment: I'd implement the `translate` function and just use arguments for this purpose.

Comment: How come we always ask the proverbial & customary 'is it homework?' on the site? Just curious...i forgot.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Also just English alphabet or all alphabets?

Comment: just the English alphabet

Comment: And version?...

Comment: @xixixixi, please always specify tag for version when you post a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that loops through each character in the string one at a time, and if it is in the set of lower case characters, apply the UPPER function, otherwise apply the LOWER function, and build your function's output string.

Comment: using the ascii to distinguish the upper and lower?

Comment: That's one way.   Another is PATINDEX with a case-sensitive collation.  (note that the range specification wouldn't work though.  Have to type out all the letters of the alphabet in the pattern to be matched):    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212110/range-wildcard-pattern-matching-behaviour-with-case-sensitive-collations

Comment: The range specification will work with a binary collation.

Comment: OK, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function where  cursor will iterate and  will pick/fetch  the String value and if its a lower case you can use the `SELECT UPPER('test string')` to change the String to upper case .If the String value is coming as Upper Case you can use the function   `SELECT lOWER('test string')` to convert to lowercase.

Comment: This is not OP asked for. look at his/her example

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state any version. For SQL Server 2017 you can use [`TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql) as suggested by Gordon.

```
WITH T(S) AS
(
SELECT 'HelloW world'
)
SELECT TRANSLATE(S COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 
                'ABCDEFGHIJLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
                'abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
FROM T
```

Comment: sorry I forgot about it, does it works on the 2016 server?

Comment: No. This is 2017 only